# Moderator Pro Tem Announcement

Tags: discussion, moderation

Throughout the beta, we need members from the site whose focus is to engage the community, both in community-building issues and site management. That's why we select a few members from each community to act as temporary, provisional Moderators. You can read about the program here: [**Moderators Pro Tempore**](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/07/moderator-pro-tempore/).

I am pleased to announce that these members have stepped up and generously volunteered their time to help us assure that each community’s issues are properly addressed:

[image: Denny Conn]
[image: mdma]
[image: jsled]

I also want to extend our sincere thanks and appreciation for the folks below who have volunteered their time to help moderate this site in the past:

[image: hookedonwinter]
[image: baka]
[image: Taylor]
[image: Nathan Koop]

Comment: When I logged in with my openId, it's using a separate account here and homebrew. Is it possible for another mod to merger the two? Thanks

Comment: Dammit man, I'm a doctor, not a database admin! (Sorry, don't have that much control)

Comment: Actually, I do have that much control.

Comment: congratulations